# Retirar o R$ do tolocalestring

Tags: javascript, formatação

Utilizo o seguinte comando pra transformar um número float para dinheiro:

```js
parseFloat(valor).toLocaleString('pt-br',{style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'})
```

Isso funciona, e esse valor utilizo para a exibição em um relatório. Porém, nesse relatório ele coloca o `R$` antes do valor, o que pro relatório é bom, mas não pra salvar no banco.

Precisava saber se existe uma maneira de pegar um valor formatado dessa maneira e retirar esse `R$`, mantendo somente o número.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta não formatar como "currency", e setar a quantidade de casas decimais para 2:

```js
let valor = '123456789.947';
console.log(parseFloat(valor).toLocaleString('pt-br',
            { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 }));

// apenas para comparar com currency
console.log(parseFloat(valor).toLocaleString('pt-br',
            { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' }));
```

O *locale* "pt-BR" mantém as configurações do separador de milhares e casas decimais (respectivamente, o ponto e a vírgula), bastando apenas acertar a quantidade de casas decimais.

[`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) usa as mesmas opções de `Intl.NumberFormat`, [veja a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) para saber todas as opções.

Vale lembrar que se tiver mais que 2 casas decimais, o valor será arredondado, como você pode notar no exemplo acima.

---

Mas se você quer salvar no banco, não salve formatado, prefira salvar apenas o número mesmo (o valor numérico). O valor formatado serve apenas para fins de apresentação (por exemplo, no banco você salva o valor numérico 1000 e só para apresentar na tela você formata como `1.000,00`).

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Usando `Intl.NumberFormat` também resolve, uma vantagem sobre o uso dessa API é como o [`@fernandosavio`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6333/fernandosavio) comentou, você pode criar um formato todo e salvar em uma variável, então poderá reaproveitar em vários lugares sem precisar ficar setando a todo momento o `formatter`, como é no `toLocaleString`:

```js
var number = 1000.01;
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR');

console.log(formatter.format(number));
console.log(formatter.format(100000));
console.log(formatter.format(99999.99));
```

Outra vantagem do `Intl.NumberFormat` é a performance, [conforme a MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat):

> When formatting large numbers of numbers, it is better to create a NumberFormat object and use the function provided by its NumberFormat.format property.

Faça um teste online da performance: https://jsbench.me/igkfvly9nf/1, `toLocaleString` foi 98% mais lento que o `Intl.NumberFormat`, resultado:

> [image: Intl.NumberFormat foi 98% mais rápido]

Comment: A vantagem dessa abordagem é que dá pra salvar o objeto "formatter" em uma variável e usar em outros lugares no código.. +1

Comment: @fernandosavio isso é otimo mesmo, uma baita mão na roda e conforme a MDN também é mais performatico, provavelmente por esse motivo que você mencionou!

Comment: Comentei antes da sua edição, mas acho que o motivo é esse mesmo.. sem contar que dá pra organizar melhor o código

Comment: @fernandosavio blz! Adicionei isso de maneira mais clara na resposta, obrigado!

Comment: Eu ia comentar sobre isso na minha resposta mas vc foi mais rápido :-)